# python.select, sending lists as arguments

Tags: python, low-level-io

`r=select([f,s],[],[])[0][0].` 
Does this mean wait until the file pointed to by f AND s is ready for readiing or f OR s is ready for reading?

Comment: The answer is OR. As answered by lvh from #python, and I completely agree, it would be the same as blocking read from all the sockets sequentially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter, although both may be returned if they're both ready for reading.